# Demo shop with Solr search

Tags: magento-enterprise, solr

Is there a Magento demo instance with the Magento Enterprise Solr search activated?

I was guessing http://enterprise-demo.magentocommerce.com/ might have activated this feature but did not find out if Solr is activated. In the admin backend, access to the system configuration is disallowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objectively - <strike>*there is no real way* to know.</strike> The Solr search integration is entirely via the back end and exposes **very few features** to the frontend on-site search that are different from the MySQL Fulltext variant. These two features are:

- Misspelling / Spelling suggestion ("did you mean" functionality)
- Related Search Terms

Because *both* of these features have to be enabled *separately*, you could, in theory, drive your search and layered navigation, even your category pages from Solr, but have no tell-tale signs on the frontend.

However, subjectively, my gut feel is that it **is** enabled. My not-so-scientific reasons:

- AJAX search dropdown is *fast*. I had suggestions in 330ms on my initial test.
- Category pages are quick, too - I got a 1.85s onload when using the [no_cache querystring parameter](http://enterprise-demo.magentocommerce.com/apparel.html?no_cache=true) on Apparel
- "Related Search Terms" appear for items that don't have explicit results:  [image]
- Wouldn't you want your demo store for a $15k annual subscription product to be best-of-breed?

**Update:**

The **default port for Solr** is 8983 - a simple curl to this port returns:

```
Authorizeds-MacBook-Pro:~ pjackson$ curl -I http://enterprise-demo.magentocommerce.com:8983/solr
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://enterprise-demo.magentocommerce.com:8983/solr/
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.3)
```

Jetty is running on this box, and Solr is *definitely* installed. Curl to the root domain on 8983 reveals that `/solr` is the only context known to Jetty. The presence of Solr/Jetty on this box **isn't conclusive proof**, but I'll take is as a pretty good indicator that they're using Solr.

Comment: As of today I can not connect to port 8983. Or did you test this from inside the Magento network ;-) ?  Would look like a security problem if they open that port to the public.

Comment: Haha maybe we got some attention! Yeah that should be hidden to the public.

Comment: I still receive the response to curl request: curl -I http://enterprise-demo.magentocommerce.com:8983/solr
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://enterprise-demo.magentocommerce.com:8983/solr/
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.3)

Comment: Silly mistake - I guess it is our firewall :-(